# How to test applications in multiple environments? - SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

We have created a SharePoint 2007 solution which we need to test in multiple environments since our dev environments are similar. But how can I test in all other environments as it is impossible to have a physical machine (or even a VM) for each and everything. For example

```
WSS 3.0 - x86, x64

x86 - SP1
      SP2
      Cumulative Updates
      Language Packs

x64 - SP1
      SP2
      Cumulative Updates
      Language Packs


MOSS 2007 - x86, x64

x86 - SP1
      SP2
      Cumulative Updates
      Language Packs

x64 - SP1
      SP2
      Cumulative Updates
      Language Packs
```

**Note**: .Net Framework version is an additional thing to take care of - 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5 SP1

So how can you test your application in all the environments and make sure it is not breaking? What are the best practices?

Comment: Physical machines aren't possible, are virtual machines?

Comment: So do we need to have 20 VMs up and running to test a component?

Comment: you dont need to have them all running at the same time, but it you want to test each environment, you are going to need to build each one, i would suggest a vm tree or something, so you dont have to build each one completely from scratch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Machines is the way to go. Don't build a new VM for every possible combination, just create a WSS3 RTM version, make a disk checkpoint / snapshot / whatever your VM platform calls it, then make changes, e.g. install SP1, and make a snapshot again.

You can then switch between checkpoints and get a clean starting point every time you start a test.

You still can't do it all in 1 VM as you need a different base for X86 and x64.

Good luck, I don't envy you.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you want to hear, but the only way to test all configurations is to actually get all configurations up and running. Of course, virtual machines are the easiest choice for this.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the above, unless you have a technical reason to use .NET 3.0 or 3.5, standardize on .NET 2.0 to reduce the number of VM images to maintain.